# Can I use Shake/Shook without a subject?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

For example, are these sentences correct?

> The boys felt their chairs shake.
>
> The desks and chairs shook.

(I mean it is nowhere mentioned who is actually responsible for shaking them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't make a sentence without a subject, unless it is a [command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood) (e.g. "Shake your body!"). In your second sentence, "the desks and chairs" is the subject. In this case, the verb has no object. Those kind of verbs are called [intransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb).

If you look up 'to shake' in a [dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb), you will see that it can be used both as an intransitive verb (without object) and as a transitive verb (with object).

Answer (score 2):

You missed a definition of "shake" that functions differently.

"shake" can be used as an **intransitive verb** meaning "for something to move or sway with short, quick, irregular vibratory movements" (Dictionary.com) or something like that. *Intransitive verbs need subjects, but do not take objects.*

The subject of the shaking in your case would be the chairs and desks. A verb cannot be without a subject, unless if it is imperative (e.g. "Shake it!").